# Breaking a string into characters and numbers separately

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like

```
HCl3C24
```

I want to break this string in php like

```
array(0 => H , 1 => Cl, 2 => 3 , 3 => C, 4 => 24)
```

Right now I am trying :

```
$matches = array();
$string = "HCl4";
preg_match_all('/([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+)/',$string,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

It's not working for characters but numbers. Could anyone please help me here ?

Comment: Don't you want `[ "H", "Cl", 3, "C", 24 ]`?

Comment: @frits : yes I want the same thing you wrote ! Do you know how can I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this regex:

```
/([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z])/
```

if you want `[ "H", "Cl", 3, "C", 24 ]` then

```
/([0-9]+|[A-Z][a-z]*)/
```

Comment: Done it. It was /([0-9]+|[.]+|[()]+|[A-Z][a-z]*)/ for my aforementioned question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also access each char of that string by treating it as an array:

```
$string = "HCl4";
echo $string[0] // prints H
echo $string[1] // prints C
echo $string[2] // prints l
echo $string[3] // prints 4
```